# passing a let value between classes / viewcontrollers in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a project with various class files. I have a barcode scanner which I have used from an online source which outputs the values in an alert controller. What I would like to do is take the barcode value and pass it back to a my main class and using a function parse it and display it in the relevant labels. For some reason I cannot get it to do this if anybody has any ideas that would be great. I have spent all day trying to figure this out without any luck.

barcodeScanner class relevant section

```
/* AVCaptureMetadataOutputObjectsDelegate */

func captureOutput(captureOutput: AVCaptureOutput!, didOutputMetadataObjects metadataObjects: [AnyObject]!, fromConnection connection: AVCaptureConnection!) {

    if alertController != nil {
        return
    }

    if metadataObjects != nil && metadataObjects.count > 0 {
        if let machineReadableCode = metadataObjects[0] as? AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject {
            // get the barcode string
            let type = machineReadableCode.type
            let barcode = machineReadableCode.stringValue
```

I need to get the barcode let value above to the passengerInformation class where it will be passed through submitCodeAuto function to write the labels.

```
            passengerInformation().self.submitCodeAuto(barcode)
```

My crack at it above which doesn't seem to work..

```
            // display the barcode in an alert
            let title = "Barcode"
            let message = "Type: \(type)\nBarcode: \(barcode)"
            displayAlert(title, message: message)
        }

    }
}

}
```

passengerInformation class

```
@IBOutlet weak var firstNameResponse: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lastNameResponse: UILabel!

@IBAction func submitCodeAuto(sender: AnyObject!) {
   firstNameResponse.text = barcodeProtocol(barcode).firstName
   lastNameResponse.text = barcodeProtocol(barcode).lastName
}
```

Above the submitCodeAuto function also sends the incoming barcode through another function called barcodeProtocol which formats it allowing for first and last name to be retrieved.

I have currently tested the labels with a button running a textfield value through barcodeProtocol and displaying in the labels so that all is working.

I have also hooked up a button to a new viewcontroller with the scanner class that works fine. Showing the camera scanning and displaying the value.

but I just haven't been able to join them up. The app is returning fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Did you do a search on the error message `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`? Did you look at the problem line indicated in Xcode? What debugging have you attempted? There are lots of similar question on StackOverflow. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32170456/558933

Answer (score 1):

In your function:

```
@IBAction func submitCodeAuto(sender: AnyObject!) {
   firstNameResponse.text = barcodeProtocol(barcode).firstName
   lastNameResponse.text = barcodeProtocol(barcode).lastName
}
```

where did you get 'barcode' from?

Try replacing it with

```
@IBAction func submitCodeAuto(sender: AnyObject!) {
   firstNameResponse.text = barcodeProtocol(sender as! String).firstName
   lastNameResponse.text = barcodeProtocol(sender as! String).lastName
}
```

I am assuming that your method barcodeProtocol takes in any string and perfectly parses it into firstname and lastname

Answer (score -1):

Your code is riddled with problems.

You create a new instance of your `passengerInformation` class from your `barcodeScanner` code, invoke the `submitCodeAuto()` method, and then forget about the newly created `passengerInformation` object. (presumably it's a view controller.)

It does not make sense to create a new view controller, send it a message, and then forget about it. That won't do anything. You probably want to instantiate your custom `passengerInformation` view controller from a storyboard, set a `barcode` string property in the view controller, and then present it modally using `presentViewController:animated:completion:`. In your `passengerInformation` view controller's viewWillAppear method, you should take the barcode property, extract the info you need from it, and install it into your text fields.

Your `submitCodeAuto()` method is declared as an IBAction even though you're not using it that way. It takes a parameter `sender` which you ignore, and instead you use a variable `barcode` which you don't show.

Your `submitCodeAuto()` function should probably take a parameter `barcode` of type String, since that's what it seems to be doing.

You have several classes who's class names start with lower-case letters. Class names should start with upper-case letters.